# How long do I have to wait with this emulator first time?

Tags: android-emulator

[image]How long Do I have to wait for this emulator to start my first time. And I am so tired of waiting. I tried to change my RAM to 1024 it didn't work it gave me error and emulator fails now I am with RAM 512 . And now it is for a long time what can I DO? How long this going to  take?!!

Comment: Sometimes, up to 15 minutes.

Comment: 15 mins already gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator is always slower than a device it is good if you can find a device to use. Otherwise you will get bored happened to me. If you don't have a device stay till the emulator starts. I hope a new version of eclipse also would help a little to make emulator work faster. For me also for the first time it really took a considerable time.